# add script tag line after the previous script indetend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mustache

I using the following code to add script tag after existing enclosing script tag (adding new script tag inside html file by code)

```
return '\n' + "<script>\n" + '\t' + scriptContent + "\n</script>\n";
```

(Script content is helloworld

The html content look like following

[image]

I want that the second opening script tag will be line after the enclosing script tag(in the first line) how can i do that ? the first '\n' doesnt help here ...

It just working when I add **br**, how can I remove this **exact** **br** if this is the only solution that i've here...

```
return "<br />" +"\n" +"<script>\n" + '\t' + scriptContent + "\n</script>\n";
```

Please have a look at the following js fiddle the both script tag are not **indented** after you click on convert...

please have a look at the following jsFiddle(similar for what I use which took from SO as reference )

> JSFiddle

[jsfiddle.net/rd0mn3wh/1](http://jsfiddle.net/rd0mn3wh/1)

as you can see when you click on **convert** both script object where not **indented** (the new script and the existing script), how can I handle it,or maybe there is better way to do it ?

I want that the new script will be add like following( the script with the alerty inside...

```
....
ui-resourceroots="{'tdrun': './'}">
     </script>
      <script>
           alert("test");
      </script>
```

I need the following:

> 1. Insert a new script after provided script ID(in the code after
>      test-ui-bootstrap')
> 2. update attribute value (when
>
>    > the key is provided)

Both below answers are doesn't help here...

Comment: Have you tried this duo: `\r\n`

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @C0dekid.php - thanks but it doesnt work...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - since I need to update some html file and I want to keep the structure of it , is it possible to do it?

Comment: Try it with the first "\n" between double quotes

Comment: @Pimskie - thanks I already tried it ...doesnt work...

Comment: @JhonD you show only one return statement, but how do you assign the script to your HTML? Do you use `append`-like function?

Comment: What are you using to add this script? is it `.text()` or `.html()` ?

Comment: Can you post the javascript code used where you define `scriptContent`, not enough just to say it contains hello world. To help make this question more complete. A perfectly complete question would include all the code but if for any reason you dont want to show all then show as much as you can.

Comment: @user454038 - please have a look at the following jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rd0mn3wh/1/  as you can see when you click on submit both script object where not indented (the new script and the existing script), how can I handle it ?

Comment: @smnbbrv  - pplease have a look at the following jsFiddle jsfiddle.net/rd0mn3wh/1 as you can see when you click on submit both script object where not indented (the new script and the existing script), how can I handle it ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan- I update the question (to avoid the xy problem :) , can you assist please,if I need to add more info please let  me know,Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `.insertAfter()` is trimming the leading white-space from your HTML string. The solution is to use `.after()` instead. I figured this out by playing with your fiddle and here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cowdd/rp1yeonx/1/).

Comment: I tested the fiddle out and this is working. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has to do with where that returned string is going to be processed.

`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, etc. are all JavaScript string escape codes and, as such, they will only work when the string is evaluated by the JavaScript runtime. If you have a JavaScript string that contains these codes and pass that string to the HTML parser (via `.innerHTML`, for example), then the HTML parser will be asked to evaluate that string, and in the HTML parser's world, `<br>` is how you add a line feed, not `\n`. That's why the `<br>` is working for you.

So, when the `\n` is evaluated by the JavaScript engine, a newline character is injected into the string, but when the HTML parser gets that newline character, it just ignores it, as it would with any carriage return in markup.

In the old days, we could get this "pretty" code by injecting it with `document.writeln()`, which would write your content and then add a line feed into the HTML. You can still do this today, but it is not considered a good practice because it requires that you inject the code inline within the HTML document, otherwise you will overwrite the entire DOM.

If this is something you just want because it will make you feel warm and fuzzy, I'd recommend forgetting about it and moving on.

Finally, here is the DOM standard way of creating new elements and injecting them into the DOM:

```js
var o = document.getElementById("output");
var scriptContent = "alert('Hello World!')";
var s = document.createElement("script");
var t = document.createTextNode(scriptContent);
s.appendChild(t);
o.appendChild(s);
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: HI Scott ,please have a look at the following jsFiddle , as you can see when you click on submit both script object where not indented (the new script and the existing script), how can I handle it ?  Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/rd0mn3wh/1/

Comment: Please see my update question, any direction how to improve the code?Thank you sir

Comment: @JhonD You need to tell us where you do want the script because it looks like it's going exactly where you told it to.

Comment: I need to add the new script after the existing script as you can see I search for it via id (test-ui-bootstrap)and add after it the new script ...does it answer your question?

Comment: You need to check your own fiddle, because the new script is going exactly in that very spot.

Comment: So what? As I've already stated in my answer (above) that is really not something you should be worried about, in fact, reducing new line characters is one of the first things that is done when files are minified.

Comment: yes I know that when it minified will remove this spaces but I still I need this, there is a way to achieve it ?

Comment: Btw, as I see you are JS expert sir ,can you please provide some feedback about the code in the fiddle,is it written OK? thank you very much for assistance !!!

Comment: Thanks sir  I saw the code but I need to create new script as I wrote in the update2 can you take a look please?

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to place the new script on a new line?

Comment: can we do the append in other place to help with this issue?

Comment: As I've already stated, the only other way to do this would be to use the very old `document.writeln()`, but this would require reworking all of your code and making it very prone to bugs.

Comment: Ok so you dont suggest to do that...as I understand , my last question can you please go over the code and see if it OK? I just want to get some feedback from an expert :)

Comment: Seeing if it is OK is a matter of opinion and not what Stack Overflow is for. That is a code review.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
return "\n<script>\n\t" + scriptContent + "\n</script>\n";
```

Comment: Although you've shortened the string by grouping strings, the code is the same.